# Python, super()

Tags: python-2.7, super

I am trying to understand how super() works in 2.7. Below is my code which is i took from stackoverflow. Kindly help me to understand what am i doing wrong?

I first invoked Base and then ChildA. These worked fine. When invoking ChildB getting the following error.TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base Created"

class ChildA(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)

class ChildB(ChildA):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChildB,self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `Base` class is using the old class style. In order to use `super` your `Base` class needs to inherit `object` as follows:

```
class Base(object):
    ...
```

Your class `ChildA` doesn't use `super` so it works while `ChildB` uses `super` and therefore generates the `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

you do not pass super with childB class 
better you can use like this
def called_class():
    print "Class assignment"
    return 2

class Bar(object):
    y = called_class()

```
def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
```

### "Class assignment"

def called_instance():
    print "Instance assignment"
    return 2

class Foo(object):
    def **init**(self, x):
        self.y = called_instance()
        self.x = x

Bar(1)
Bar(2)
Foo(1)

### "Instance assignment"

which inherits all the properties of parent and child class to acess